# Ещё раз о числительных

Tags: числительные

«Были заявления всех трёх первых лиц исполнительной власти США. Керри, Байдена и  самого президента Обамы». От журналиста Валерия Отставных фраза. Как отредактировать, чтобы не напоминала известное — два дня без первого и три без второго? «Первое лицо» — фразеологизм?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, конечно, всё не настолько сурово, как в узаконенном сочетании "первый вице-премьер" (этимологически, "первый среди вторых первых"), но...

Можно было бы сказать о "**трёх первых** лицах" разных государств, но в данном случае **первое лицо** (устойчивое сочетание) исполнительной власти государства *одно* "по определению" - это президент, поэтому здесь логическая *ошибка*. В духе этого фразеологизма, можно было бы переставить местами слова и сказать "**первых трёх** лиц", но это требует введения понятий "второе лицо" и "третье лицо" (исполнительной власти) - существует ли в Штатах такая формальная иерархия? Поэтому спокойнее сказать "*трёх высших руководителей*..." и т. п.

Comment: Или «руководителей». Они же в количестве трёх штук следом поимённо идут. Полностью согласен.

Answer (score 0):

> Как отредактировать, чтобы не напоминала известное — два дня без первого и три без второго?

А оно напоминает? Да, первое лицо - фразеологизм, но не в этом дело. Если сказать "трех колючих ёжиков", вы не отнесете "трех" к колючим или к ежикам? Так и тут. Трех лиц прежде всего, а не трех первых. Надо очень постараться, чтобы увидеть двусмысленность.

Comment: И напоминает. Память, знаете ли. И напоминает, и в чём-то превосходит по накалу из-за ВСЕХ (трёх первых лиц). Видно, что журналист просто из штанов выпрыгивает. Хотя, бывает что и менее трёх, — «со всех ног», например.

Comment: У этого автора перлы, похоже, в каждом материале. Слёту такое вот увидел: «Квартиры оказались размороженными, начали болеть дети... И вот цыгане решились на отчаянный шаг, они сами врезались в трубы... На подступах к поселку цыгане начали жечь «майданные покрышки».

Comment: Я не вижу тут ничего такого вопиющего. И "музыкант" играет как умеет, никаких особенных штанов. Примеры Ваши вообще не понятны без контекста, а по поводу исходного: "три первых места" Вас не смущает? Под которыми понимают первое, второе и третье? Три первых лица - это первое, второе и третье. Да, шероховато, но не настолько же, чтоб журналиста в бетон закатывать?

Comment: У одной власти должно быть одно лицо. Если у власти три ветви, — по одному на каждую. Первое, второе и третье не проходит по соображениям равенства этих ветвей или пьедестала, как в непонятно почему исходном — «три первых места».

Comment: "У одной власти должно быть одно лицо" - не согласен. "Второе лицо" - столь же понятная вещь, как и первое. Вопрос скорее в том, есть ли вообще "лицо" у *власти*, особенно у *исполнительной*.

Comment: По поводу наличности лиц соглашусь с behemothus: «Первое лицо — а то даже и не одно — может быть у государства». В зависимости от устройства два-три. Вторых лиц — говорите, понятная вещь — в наших властях (например, в законодательной) мы даже и не знаем.

Answer (score 0):

Исправить можно на "***Три высших должностных лица***". 
Не уверен, правда, что надо и насколько надо. Пока не прочитал другие ответы был даже уверен, что не надо, ибо в официальной речи оборот "первое лицо" в принципе не должен иметь, т. е. если и править, то совсем не стечение двух числительных - и не по этой причине. А если текст неофициальный, то и так все нормально выглядит.

Аргумент Alex_andr'а, что, дескать, "первое лицо" - оно же и единственное в отдельном взятом государстве, мне кажется не совсем верным ("первое лицо" - это не совсем синоним "главы государства", это немного шире), но коли так воспринимается, то можно и поправить.

Подумалось... Тут другое, правда, надо бы учесть. Первое лицо - а то даже и не одно - может быть у **государства** как такового, но ни у чего другого, пусть даже у исполнительной власти этого государства. Вот с этих позиций поменять надо.

Comment: *>> Первое лицо - а то даже и не одно - может быть у государства как такового, но ни у чего другого...* Редкая ерунда, но сами напросились. Первое лицо (первые лица) города, предприятия, футбольного клуба... Можно много перечислять.

Comment: *Редкая ерунда, но сами напросились. Первое лицо (первые лица) города, предприятия, футбольного клуба... Можно много перечислять* - я не напрашивался читать столько чуши. Это Вы простите, по собственной инициативе. Только ставьте в следующий раз подпись в начало комментария, гр. Редкая ерунда. .

Comment: Видите, а говорили — мне сказать нечего. Осторожнее в следующий раз будьте. )))

Comment: Чего мне осторожничать? Или Вы еще и заразный?

Comment: Чего? Да просто подобной ерунды старайтесь больше не писать - насчет "первых лиц". А после драки-то чего кулаками махать. ))

Comment: Niemand, вы ко всем так придираетесь или выборочно?

Comment: behemothus, я не совсем понял, Вы видите проблему в "трех первых", "лице исполнительной власти" или и там и там? Мне кажется, что правильно - последнее. По отдельности это было бы еще терпимо. Да, согласен, первое лицо исполнительной власти - не очень, как "вождь *отряда* команчей". Но терпимо. И три первых лица - тоже. Вместе - перебор.